# AWS::CloudFormation::Stack failed to ROLLBACK

Tags: aws-cloudformation

My cloudformation template had couple of AWS::SNS::Subscription. I removed those and deployed the template. 1 of those 2 AWS::SNS::Subscription failed to delete and ended up in DELETE_FAILED. I expected the AWS::CloudFormation::Stack to ROLLBACK on failure to delete the AWS::SNS::Subscription. But to my surprise it ended up in UPDATE_COMPLETE state.

Comment: Did you check through UI if the subscription is still there? Maybe it deleted them in a retry.

Comment: Yes the subscription still exists

Answer (score 1):

Generally if CloudFormation can't delete a resource as part of the cleanup step, it does not rollback, but succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

No Worry!! Now AWS added new features and ability to retry the stack operations from the point of failure.

This is amazing!! While I was using AWS Cloudformation, I faced the same problem when any resources fail to launch for any reason and we have to wait for the rolls back and again we have to launch the stack from the scratch. But now we can retry stack operations from the point of failure.

Thanks to AWS for adding this new features in it.

Still do you have any questions regarding the same please let me know in the comments section.

Get the full details here : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-cloudformation-quickly-retry-stack-operations-from-the-point-of-failure/